# Dynamic array index in PHP

Tags: php

I don't know why I'm having trouble figuring this out, but I'm hoping someone can help.

I want to dynamically add multiple indices to an array. For example, if I have a list of IDs.

```
$ids = array(1247, 1248);
```

How can I do this dynamically, depending on the number of ids that are in the array?

```
$history['transactions'][$id1][$id2]['Thursday'] = 0;
```

Comment: no idea what you are asking

Comment: What do you want the resulting array to look like? This doesn't exactly make sense to dynamically create _depth_ in your array with essentially unknown keys (which is what your attempt does)

Comment: arrays are dynamic in `PHP` you can add to them as you want pretty much. They are actually hash tables

Comment: @Dagon: He wants to dynamically create an array based on how elements are in `$ids`.  For example: `$history['transactions'][1247][1248]['Thursday']`.  There could be more `[xxx]` based on the number of elements.

Comment: We need an example of the result you expect..

Comment: I think knowing how to ask a question is more important than the question in question....

Comment: I question this question with another question. What is the question?

Comment: If you second guess the decision to visit an Indian reservation, would that be a Reservation Reservation reservation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am unserstanding you correctly, then your code should work. unless you are trying to use the array your created, take a look. I think a simple change could solve your problem

this would work:

```
$ids = array(1247, 1248);
$history['transactions'][$ids[0]][$ids[1]]['Thursday'] = 0;
```

So would this:

```
$id1 = 1247;
$id2 = 1248;
$history['transactions'][$id1][$id2]['Thursday'] = 0;
```

From the looks of it, you just aren't calling anything. but without more of your code I can't be more help

---

As Daedalus points out, to this point the code isn't really dynamic, (I assumed you just needed a snipit in the the middle to help with already dynamic code. but now I will assume the opposite) here is an example of how how to change that:

say you had the array `$ids = array(1247, 1248, 1249, 1250, 1251);` you would need to loop through the lot of them and deal with them individually. Probably the easiest way to do that would be something like:

```
$ids = array(1247, 1248, 1249, 1250, 1251);
foreach($ids as $id){
    $history['transactions'][$id]['Thursday'] = 0;
}
```

Make sense?

---

Third try:
Getting a better understanding of whats going on. (sorry, took a long time to get it through my thick skull)

So if you want an array with all the ids in order of the array `$ids = array(1247, 1248, 1249, 1250, 1251);` then this is the solution for you:

```
$ids = array(1247, 1248, 1249, 1250, 1251);
$result = array('Thursday' => 0);
for($i = count($ids) -1; $i >= 0; $i--){
     $result = array($ids[$i] => $result);
}
$history = array('transactions' => $result);
```

`var_dump($history)` yields:

```
array(1) {
  ["transactions"]=>
  array(1) {
    [1247]=>
    array(1) {
      [1248]=>
      array(1) {
        [1249]=>
        array(1) {
          [1250]=>
          array(1) {
            [1251]=>
            array(1) {
              ["Thursday"]=>
              int(0)
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Which is now what I believe you are looking for

Comment: This isn't dynamic.  `$ids` could be of any size.

Comment: yeah I realize that was wrong... looked at it after posting. Wouldn't it being dynamic depend on the rest of the code?

Comment: Dynamic would be the ability to create the depth of the array according to the length of the `$ids` array, with each sub-array having the key of the requisite id.  The question the user is asking is how to create the array dynamically.. in the previously noted way.  This is what the OP is asking.

Comment: Pretty sure it isn't, unless it outputs `array(1247 => array(1248 => array(1249 => array(1250 => array(1251 => array('Thursday'=> 0))))))`

Comment: This is what the OP has been looking for :D!

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you explain better what's your problem, we could help in a better way that explaining you how to create arrays like this:

```
$history['transactions'][$id1][$id2]['Thursday'] = 0;
```

depending on how much ids there are in a array. For sure you can do what you want do to in a better way.

Or, just try to think some other way than putting ids as parameters of an array.

Comment: Answers are reserved for attempts to answer the question.  This makes no attempt to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use references to achieve this very dynamically, but I don't understand the reason to do this...

```
$ids = array(1247, 1248);
$data = &$history['transactions'];
foreach ($ids as $id) {
    $data = &$data[$id];
}
$data['Thursday'] = 0;
```